# Vim multiply column of numbers by series of numbers

Tags: math, vim

I have a column of numbers in my text file that looks like this:

```
10  1  -0.93
11  1  -0.93
12  1  -0.93
13  1  -0.93
...
```

(The first column of numbers is *not* the line number.)

I would like to replace the last column of numbers by multiplying each one by `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3`, etc. such that the result is

```
10  1  -0.093
11  1  -0.186
12  1  -0.279
13  1  -0.372
...
```

I know I can do math using the `=` register (is that the right terminology?), but I can't seem to figure out how to automate this. Please advise.

Comment: Does this need to be done in vim? Might be easier using `awk`

Comment: Yes, I'll be actively editing. I don't have a problem if Vim calls awk to get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `0.1`/`0.2`/... correpond to "line number / 10", you can use

```
%s/\v(\S+)$/\=str2float(submatch(1)) * line('.') * 0.1
```

which captures the last column and return the result of "value * line_number * 0.1" using a
sub-replace-expression (see `:help sub-replace-expression` for more info on this).

---

If the values don't start on line 1 you could use a visual selection (to set `line("'<")`) and use `line('.') - line("'<") + 1` to know where you are in the block. Then add the initial multiplier (`0.1` here):

```
'<,'>s/\v(\S+)$/\=str2float(submatch(1)) * (line('.') - line("'<") + 1) * 0.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the line numbers have no bearing on the multiplication value. I'm looking for something more generic.

Comment: @jlconlin: I added way to handle blocks that do not start on line 1.  Though I'm not sure that's what you want. If you want to be able to apply the operation on multiple lines/blocks (i.e do the computation and increment the multiplier) then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with `awk` (both to read and use) if you're ok making a copy of your data file that gets deleted immediately (i.e. don't use if your data file is massive).

Try:

```
: ! awk '{ $NF=$NF*(0.1 * NR); print}' data_file > tmp && mv tmp data_file
```

Use `!` to run the command outside of Vim in your terminal. Then for each line in your `data_file`, `awk` replaces the last column `$NF` with itself multiplied by `(0.1 * NR)` where `NR` is the row number. You can change this with whatever math logic you want. Then it prints the entire line with your modification.

Now, you just need to store this output in a temporary file `tmp` and then overwrite your `data_file` with the modified data, hence the `mv` command.

Vim will ask you to reload the file, which you should to load in the newly modified data.